# Php compare strings and return common values

Tags: php, string, compare

I have tried to find other posts/information on this and none of them seem to work - although I'm sure this is a simple task.

I have two strings, and I would like to have some lines of code that give me the word that they have in common.

For example, I may have...

```
String1 = "Product Name - Blue";
String2 = "Blue Green Pink Black Orange";
```

And I would like to have a string only containing the value Blue.  How can I do this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) maybe?

[Demo here](http://www.ideone.com/DnI0H) & [here](http://www.ideone.com/NT553)

```
<?php
 
  function common($str1,$str2,$case_sensitive = false)
  {
    $ary1 = explode(' ',$str1);
    $ary2 = explode(' ',$str2);

    if ($case_sensitive)
    {
      $ary1 = array_map('strtolower',$ary1);
      $ary2 = array_map('strtolower',$ary2);
    }

    return implode(' ',array_intersect($ary1,$ary2));
  }
 
  echo common('Product Name - Blue','Blue Green Pink Black Orange');
```

Returns "Blue";

**EDIT** Updated it to include a case-insensitive version if you'd like it.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but wouldn't that only work if both instances of "blue" begin with a capital b?  It sounds like he may need to create his own function to mimic array_intersect but case insensitive.  EDIT: It seems you edited to account for this.  Well done.

Comment: yes, the lowercase addition is useful.  Do you know of any way to add the ability to check a segment of words.  For example: instead of **blue**, match something like **purple owl**?

Comment: @thepristinedesign: Can you give two string examples and desired outcome?

Comment: String1 = "NVEY - Lipstick (Muted Coral Pink)"; String2 = "muted coral pink, style2, style3, etc..";  Desired outcome would be -> muted coral pink

Comment: @theprestinedesign: Is the second string always CSV?

Comment: well it actually also starts as an array, but for simplicity I listed it as a CSV string.  I am assuming I could always explode that array to get the CSV string like the example I gave above in string2.

Comment: @theprestinedesign: Based on what you're telling me, you iterate over the second array and use `stripos` or `strpos` and check for a value that's not **FALSE**. When an element has been found, it's a match. `foreach ($ary2 as $a2) if (stripos($a2,$str1) !== false) return $a2;` sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

A solution would be to split your strings into two arrays of words -- using [**`explode()`**](https://www.php.net/explode), for instance :

```
$string1 = "Product Name - Blue";
$string2 = "Blue Green Pink Black Orange";

$arr1 = explode(' ', $string1);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $string2);
```

*Note that `explode()` is a basic solution ; you might want to use something a bit more complex, like [`preg_split()`](http://fr.php.net/preg_split), which allows for more specific delimiters.*

And, then, to use [**`array_intersect()`**][3] on those arrays, to find out which words are present in both :

```
$common = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
var_dump($common);
```

Which, in this case, would give :

```
array
  3 => string 'Blue' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an explode() on each list to separate them into arrays, then use array_intersect() to find the common words in both arrays.