# compare two string and return different value in php

Tags: php, string

```
$a = "what go around, come around";
$b = "what goes around, comes around";
```

when comparing `$a` and `$b`, it will return an array `$arr = {"goes","comes"}` from `$b` that is different from `$a`. Please suggest a solution

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `$arr = array_diff(str_word_count($b, 2), str_word_count($a, 2));`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736781/php-compare-strings-and-return-common-values

Comment: @MarkBaker That's a great answer please post it as an answer. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `preg_split` along with `array_diff` like as

```
$a = "what go around, come around";
$b = "what goes around, comes around";
echo implode(',',array_diff(preg_split('/\h/',$b),preg_split('/\h/',$a)));
```

**Output:**

```
goes,comes
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/446167)

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with PHP [array_diff()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp) function.

```
array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

It compares `array1` against one or more other arrays and returns the values in `array1` that are not present in any of the other arrays.