# Get words that are matching in second string in PHP

Tags: php

I have two strings

```
$str_original='This is first string';
$user_string='This is user string';
```

i want to get all the words that are matching with `str_original` string

Required output:

```
This is string
```

I can get this results using loop  but is there any faster way to achieve this result using any function.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `explode` and `array_intersect`?

Comment: This means that the comparison would be order independent, which is probably good.  It also means that it's case sensitive, which might not be, depending on the use case.  But it is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has already been answered here:
[Php compare strings and return common values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736781/php-compare-strings-and-return-common-values)

You can just replace the string with the variables while calling the function common from the above solved answer:

Replace:

```
echo common('Product Name - Blue','Blue Green Pink Black Orange');
```

With:

```
echo common($str_original,$user_string);
```

where you can make `str_original` and `user_string` dynamic.

Comment: this is a good answer for this (it is what Abracadaver suggested in comments), but you should probably include more of the code from the link, even though it is already answered there.  That link might go away, if the user deleted their account, for instance, or just the question, or for some other reason, and then this answer would be useless, without functional code or even the indication that this solution uses explode and array_intersect.